# Debugging the canvas texture code in A-Frame (FFmpeg stream as canvas source)

Tags: php, ffmpeg, aframe

I am attempting to display a canvas as a texture in A-Frame. The canvas image is a video stream fed in from FFmpeg. This feed displays fine on the regular 2d canvas example from https://github.com/sbidolach/video-live-streaming , but I'm just getting a blank browser window when attempting to bring the code for reading FFmpeg to Canvas into the A-frame page structure.

Please find below my current revision, any help debugging it would be greatly appreciated:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsmpg.js"></script>




  </head>
  <body>


              <script>

                // Setup the WebSocket connection and start the player
                var client = new WebSocket( 'ws://127.0.0.1:8084/' );
                var canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
                var player = new jsmpeg(client, {canvas:canvas});

              </script>

              
    <script>

        AFRAME.registerComponent('draw-canvas', {
          schema: {default: ''},
          init: function () {
            this.canvas = document.getElementById(this.data);
            this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

          }
        });
      </script>


      <a-scene>

<a-assets>
  <canvas id="my-canvas" crossorigin="anonymous"></canvas>
</a-assets>

<a-entity geometry="primitive: plane"
          material="src: #my-canvas"
          draw-canvas="my-canvas"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors, in the browser console ?

Comment: I was getting a few, I made a few adjustments and there's no errors now, but the a-frame scene is still showing up blank in the browser (The code example here has been updated to the latest revision)

Comment: Are you styling the canvas as the https://github.com/sbidolach/video-live-streaming , example? https://github.com/sbidolach/video-live-streaming/blob/master/public/stream-jsmpeg.html#L15

Comment: I've tried it, but it just changes the background colour, but the canvas is still invisible. I added in a border colour to the canvas in CSS to try make it visible, but no joy!

Comment: @MrDiago did You try to display the canvas outside the scene, to see if it has the desired feed ? Try embedding the scene, and placing the scene, and canvas next to each other like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y1derjt2/6/)

Comment: I got it working, many thanks Piotr and Diego for your help! Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/fgxjxLsu/ I'm using it to display a live capture from my desktop, it's pretty much zero latency, much better than the results I've had embedding HLS streams that had 3 to 5 second delays. The only caveat is that there's no audio, but that could be worked around with a separate feed... Screencast to follow!

Comment: Here's a quick video of it in action: https://twitter.com/kierannolan/status/959185719800614919 - many thanks again for all your help